# Unir retornos de query para ser populado um combochart

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli, google-charts

Tenho 2 consultas no banco:

> Uma retorna as metas do dia até o ultimo dia do mês:

```
DIA META
1   3,23
2   6,45
3   9,68
4   12,9
5   16,13
6   19,35
7   22,58
8   25,81
9   29,03
10  32,26
11  35,48
12  38,71
13  41,94
14  45,16
15  48,39
16  51,61
17  54,84
18  58,06
19  61,29
20  64,52
21  67,74
22  70,97
23  74,19
24  77,42
25  80,65
26  83,87
27  87,1
28  90,32
29  93,55
30  96,77
31  100
```

> A outra mostra os valores alcançados até o dia da consulta:

```
DIA REALIZADO
1   4,35
2   8,69
3   13,12
4   17,05
5   21,39
6   25,65
7   30,12
8   34,49
9   38,85
```

Como que posso uni-los para popular o combo chart como ilustrado na imagem abaixo:

> Sendo o primeiro na linha como meta e o segundo nas colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando o seguinte chart:
 [combochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)

> Tentei colocar dentro de um array só os demais arrays mais sem
>   sucesso:

```
Array
(
    [dados] => Array
        (
            [realizado] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4,35
                    [1] => 8,69
                    [2] => 13,12
                    [3] => 17,05
                    [4] => 21,39
                    [5] => 25,65
                    [6] => 30,12
                    [7] => 34,49
                    [8] => 38,85
                )

            [dias] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 5
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 7
                    [7] => 8
                    [8] => 9
                    [9] => 10
                    [10] => 11
                    [11] => 12
                    [12] => 13
                    [13] => 14
                    [14] => 15
                    [15] => 16
                    [16] => 17
                    [17] => 18
                    [18] => 19
                    [19] => 20
                    [20] => 21
                    [21] => 22
                    [22] => 23
                    [23] => 24
                    [24] => 25
                    [25] => 26
                    [26] => 27
                    [27] => 28
                    [28] => 29
                    [29] => 30
                    [30] => 31
                )

            [meta] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3,23
                    [1] => 6,45
                    [2] => 9,68
                    [3] => 12,90
                    [4] => 16,13
                    [5] => 19,35
                    [6] => 22,58
                    [7] => 25,81
                    [8] => 29,03
                    [9] => 32,26
                    [10] => 35,48
                    [11] => 38,71
                    [12] => 41,94
                    [13] => 45,16
                    [14] => 48,39
                    [15] => 51,61
                    [16] => 54,84
                    [17] => 58,06
                    [18] => 61,29
                    [19] => 64,52
                    [20] => 67,74
                    [21] => 70,97
                    [22] => 74,19
                    [23] => 77,42
                    [24] => 80,65
                    [25] => 83,87
                    [26] => 87,10
                    [27] => 90,32
                    [28] => 93,55
                    [29] => 96,77
                    [30] => 100,00
                )

        )

)
```

> Segue as consultas:

```
include 'conexao.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hoje = date('d');

$loja = '5';
$mes = '3';
$ano = '2018';
$acumReal = '';
$acumMeta = '';
$data        = array();

$consultaRealizadoLoja = "SELECT *,
DAY(rl_data) AS DIA,
MONTH(rl_data) AS MES 
FROM realizado_loja
WHERE rl_loja = '$loja'
AND MONTH(rl_data) = '$mes'";

$consultaMetaMes = "SELECT 
saz_loja_mes AS meta_mes 
FROM 
vi_sazo_energia_loja 
WHERE
loja = '$loja'
AND mes = '$mes'";

$consultaMetaDia = "SELECT 
saz_loja_dia AS meta_dia 
FROM 
vi_sazo_energia_loja 
WHERE
loja = '$loja'
AND mes = '$mes'";

$consultaDiasMes = "SELECT 
dias AS d 
FROM 
vi_sazo_anual
WHERE mes = '$mes'";

$resultRealizadoLoja = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaRealizadoLoja);
$resultMetaMes       = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaMetaMes);
$resultMetaDia           = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaMetaDia);
$resultDiasMes       = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaDiasMes);

while($rowMetaMes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultMetaMes)) {
    $metaMes = $rowMetaMes['meta_mes']."<br>";
}
while($rowMetaDia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultMetaDia)) {
    $metaDiaria = $rowMetaDia['meta_dia']."<br>";
}
while($rowDiasMes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDiasMes)) {
    $diasMes = $rowDiasMes['d']."<br>";
}

// FAZ O ACUMULADO DO REALIZADO
while($rowRealizadoLoja = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultRealizadoLoja)) {
    $dia = $rowRealizadoLoja['DIA'];
    $retorno = $rowRealizadoLoja['rl_valor'];
    $acumReal = $retorno + $acumReal ;
    $calculo = ( $acumReal / $metaMes * 100 );
    $realizadoFinal =  number_format($calculo,2,",",".");

    $data['dados']['realizado'][] = $realizadoFinal;
}

//FAZ ACULADO DA META
for ($i=1; $i <= $diasMes  ; $i++) { 
    $acumMeta = $metaDiaria + $acumMeta ;
    $calculo2 = ( $acumMeta / $metaMes * 100 );
    $acumuladoMeta =  number_format($calculo2,2,",",".");

    $data['dados']['dias'][] = $i;
    $data['dados']['meta'][] = $acumuladoMeta;
}
```

O gráfico precisa retornar exatamente dessa forma:
https://jsfiddle.net/j0x8wzaf/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $array_dados = $data;
$exibir_chart = '';
    for( $x=0; $x < count($array_dados['dados']['dias']); $x++ ){
    $exibir_chart .= '[\'' . $array_dados['dados']['dias'][$x] . '\', ' . str_replace(',', '.', $array_dados['dados']['meta'][$x]) . ',  ' . (isset($array_dados['dados']['realizado'][$x])?str_replace(',', '.', $array_dados['dados']['realizado'][$x]):'0.00' ) . '],' . PHP_EOL;

    }
    $exibir_chart = substr(trim($exibir_chart), 0, -1);
    // echo $exibir_chart;
```

Comment: Para formatar selecione o código e aperte `CTRL+K`, use **snippet** apenas para códigos *HTML / JavaScript*. Aproveite e explique sua resposta!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/E7h7P9G8

Comment: Coloquei um loop para pegar os dias da array e a partir dela gerar os dados de todos os dias. O str_replace pra mudar as virgulas para pontos. E o isset pra verificar se tem o dado, caso não tiver ele coloca como 0.00 . O que eu postei deve ser postado depois do código dele e o echo deve ser colocado no javascript que deve estar inline.

Comment: Coloque na resposta! Faça [**Tour**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, leia os tópicos [**Como faço para escrever uma boa resposta?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), [**Ajuda na edição do Markdown**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem o seu problema, acho que isto deve resolver.

Assumindo que o vetor de dias sempre será o maior de todos os três vetores, você pode tentar algo assim

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dias); $i++) {
    $result[] =[
        isset($dias[$i]) ?? $dias[$i]: 0,
        isset($meta[$i]) ? $meta[$i]: 0,
        isset($realizado[$i]) ? $realizado[$i]: 0
    ];
}
```

Ou você pode utilizar o operador de coalescência nula do PHP 7.x+ e fazer algo assim

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dias); $i++) {
    $result[] =[$dias[$i] ?? 0, $meta[$i] ?? 0, $realizado[$i] ?? 0];
}
```

Ao final de qualquer um dos laços, você executa

```
$header = ['DIA', 'META', 'REALIZADO'];
array_unshift($result, $header);
```

Isto vai colocar o vetor $header na primeira posição de $result.